# FirestoreException: Backend ended Listen Stream

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use Firestore in order to set up realtime listeners for a collection. Whenever a document is added, modified, or deleted in a collection, I want the listener to be called. My code is currently working for one collection, but when I try the same code on a larger collection, it fails with the error:

> Listen failed: com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: Backend ended Listen stream: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.

Here's my actual listener code:

```
/**
 * Sets up a listener at the given collection reference. When changes are made in this collection, it writes a flat
 * text file for import into backend.
 * @param collectionReference The Collection Reference that we want to listen to for changes.
 */
public static void listenToCollection(CollectionReference collectionReference) {

    AtomicBoolean initialUpdate = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    System.out.println("Initializing listener for: " + collectionReference.getId());

    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
            // Error Handling
            if (e != null) {
                System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
                return;
            }

            // If this is the first time this function is called, it's simply reading everything in the collection
            // We don't care about the initial value, only the updates, so we simply ignore the first call
            if (initialUpdate.get()) {
                initialUpdate.set(false);
                System.out.println("Initial update complete...\nListener active for " + collectionReference.getId() + "...");
                return;
            }

            // A document has changed, propagate this back to backend by writing text file.
            for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                String docId = dc.getDocument().getId();
                Map<String, Object> docData = dc.getDocument().getData();

                String folderPath = createFolderPath(collectionReference, docId, docData);

                switch (dc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        System.out.println("Document Created: " + docId);
                        writeMapToFile(docData, folderPath, "CREATE");
                        break;
                    case MODIFIED:
                        System.out.println("Document Updated: " + docId);
                        writeMapToFile(docData, folderPath, "UPDATE");
                        break;
                    case REMOVED:
                        System.out.println("Document Deleted: " + docId);
                        writeMapToFile(docData, folderPath, "DELETE");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

It seems to me that the collection is too large, and the initial download of the collection is timing out. Is there some sort of work around I can use in order to get updates to this collection in real time?

Comment: Please add your database structure and show us what are the collections that you want to listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the Firebase team, and they're currently getting back to me on the issue. In the meantime, I was able to reduce the size of my listener by querying the collection based on a *Last Updated* timestamp attribute. I only looked at documents that were recently updated, and had my app change this attribute whenever a change was made.

Comment: Any news from regarding this? I have huge collections and I'm running in the same problem.